# To capture the FILTER list in EXCEL 2007

Tags: excel, vba

I have the xls -2007 with huge data in which I want to capture the FILTER list on one of the column, could someone please let me know if this is possible using VBA and how can I do it?

Answer (score -3):

The trick is to keep the list visable when you "alt-print screen" to capture the image.  You do this by activating the filter list so it shows, then with your mouse over the list image you press and hold down the right mouse button (this keeps the image visible) and while continuing to hold the right mouse button down, press the alt-print screen key combination to capture the image to memory -then its just a matter of pasting that to word/word pad or where ever.